# Facebook intent in Android to screen with live video

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, live-video

I have a Facebook video link (it can be live or not live) from backend. When I press button in my android app I want to open Facebook app on the page with this video. I use the following code for this:

```
val videoUrl = "some fb video url from backend"
val uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=$videoUrl")
val facebookAppIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
startActivity(facebookAppIntent)
```

and it works fine, but only with NOT live videos. When I try to open facebook app with live video link, I have an error in Facebook screen. So, how to resolve this problem?